# Django: Is it possible to exclude fields in view?

Tags: django, forms, templates, view, django-crispy-forms

I need to exclude some of my form's fields in the view. I know it is possible to do in the actual form with `.exclude` function, but in that case I'd need to make one form for each case.
I can't do this in the template because I'm using `crispy_forms.helper`, calling it in the template with `{% crispy form %}`, otherwise I would iterate over fields and exclude which I need.

I would need to do something like:

```
form = ArtiForm(instance=Articulo.objects.get(codigo=arti), filter_on=request.session['codEmp']).exclude(field)
```

But `exclude` is not a form attr in view.
Any way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form has a `fields` dictionary which is modifiable. So you can do:

```
form.pop(field)
```

after instantiating it but before calling `is_valid()`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
form.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33378391)